# Can't find component from other module angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I declare AppModule and import my HomeModule.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HomeModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

That is my HomeModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    Page404Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
    MainModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule

  ],
  providers: []
})
export class HomeModule { 

}
```

Next i try to add into `app.component` a `home.component` so I made something like this:

```
@Component({


     selector: 'em-home',
      templateUrl: './home.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
   })
    export class HomeComponent {
}
```

To AppComponent.html :

```
<div>
<em-home></em-home>
</div>
```

And then i receive errors in my browser :

```
'em-home' is not a known element:
1. If 'em-home' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'em-home' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<div>
[ERROR ->]<em-home></em-home>
```

Could anyone explain me what is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `exports` in the home module components.

You should add it here :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    Page404Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
    MainModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule

  ],
exports:[HomeComponent,
        ContactComponent,
        Page404Component], //<--here
providers: []
})
export class HomeModule { 

}
```

NB , you don't need to export providers though.

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` like it gives me loop

Comment: I have to export : `HomeComponent`